# How to prevent Axios request from converting object to string?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, axios

So when when my axios request posts to my server it is converting my req header to a string. So if I `console.log(data)` I get the following...
[image]

And then when I `console.log(req.body)` from my server I get...

```
 { title: 'test 2',
  start: '2018-10-13T05:00:00.000Z',
end: '2018-10-13T05:00:00.000Z',
color: 'blue' }
```

Why is it converting my `start` and `end` to a String? And how do I keep it as the `Date` object?

**Edit**

**Axios Post**

```
   export const addEvent = eventData => dispatch => {
      console.log(eventData);
      dispatch(setEventsLoading());
      axios
        .post("/api/events/", eventData)
...
```

Comment: Whats your `axios.post()` look like?

Answer (score 1):

When you get result from the server it will return the data as JSON. JSON doesn't know anything about dates as you can read here [[The "right" JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format][1]). All you can do is convert the data returned into date. You can use library like moments to covert string into date format

Comment: I was thinking I was going to have to do that. I wasn't sure if I could change how the headers are sent. Thanks!